# What does し do here? 「そのほうが頭の固いお方にもご理解いただけそうですし。 」

Tags: meaning, particle-し

The sentence where I found this occurance is そのほうが頭の固いお方にもご理解いただけそうですし.

The only explanations I found are "(at the end of a phrase) notes one (of several) reasons" and "at sentence end; gives reason for an unstated but deducible conclusion". I'm uncertain if any of these fit, however.

Would the sentence be significantly different if it were to simply end with です rather than ですし?

Comment: I think I read this sentence somewhere before but I can't remember which. Can you tell me the source?

Comment: Oh right, Stein's Gate?

Comment: Yeah, it's Steins;Gate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're seeing the correct definition of this し. This し is a kind of reason marker. It's adding a sense of "cuz" or "you know".

> そのほうが頭の固いお方にもご理解いただけそうですし。
>
> *(Because)* that way, those with rigid minds might be able to comprehend it *(you know)*.

Related:

- [Usage of ”し” particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28096/5010)
- [し at the end of the sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58439/5010)

Comment: What's the difference between the particles し and よ at the end of a sentence?

Comment: @cmw よ works in this context, too, but よ is a more generic sentence-end particle to seek agreement or emphasize the statement.