# Can し act as replacement for て when listing a series of adjectives?

Tags: conjunctions, particle-し

I was watching an anime and one of the characters said this:

> 優しいししっかりしてるし可愛いし

I was a bit surprised because I was told that you should connect adjectives with て.

Why is this characters using し here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usage of ”し”　particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28096/usage-of-%e3%81%97-particle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the character said

> 優しいししっかりしてるし可愛いし

It roughly translates to

> He is nice, *plus* mature, *plus* cute.

If you were to use て、
you would not say
優しいて、
you would say
優しくて.

Here, 
優しいし
is used because it is a little more informal than 優しくて.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When using し after an adjective, it conveys the idea that it's explaining one of many reasons. So when you do this 「〜し、〜し、〜し」 form, I think it emphasizes that there are numerous reasons.

Comment: Thanks fro the answer. I thought て also listed many reasons. What's the difference?

Comment: @alex し can stand for reason by itself, while て can't unless it's combined with other elements.