# The meaning of し in the following context (maybe duplicate, maybe not)

Tags: grammar

I have a hard time figuring out the meaning of し　in the following sentence

> 暗いし付いて行ってあげようか
>
> It's dark outside. Want me to go out with you ?

Is it the し　that serves to link two sentences together like the て　in
[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/%e3%81%a6-versus-combining-form-for-joining-clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/%E3%81%A6-versus-combining-form-for-joining-clauses) ?

It seems a bit strange to me because

- the subject is not the same
- I feel that the first sentence has a
  more causative meaning: since it's dark ...

Could you clarify ?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70179/why-was-%e3%81%97-used-instead-of-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89 and this one: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55597/%e3%81%97-grammar-question

Comment: @user3856370 thanks for the links !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood thanks to the link provided by – user3856370 [https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55597/%e3%81%97-grammar-question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55597/%E3%81%97-grammar-question)

this し denotes indeed a reason.

Other examples were provided in the link

> 遅くなったし、もう帰ろう。 It's already late, so let's go back.
>
> だって怖かったし。 Well, coz
> I was scared.