# Difference in たくて and てwhen joining two (or more) sentences

Tags: conjugations

What's the difference between:

食堂に行って、ご飯を食べたい - I want to go to the cafeteria and want to eat rice

食堂に行きたくて、ご飯を食べたい - I want to go to the cafeteria and want to eat rice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to say the former, "食堂に行って、ご飯を食べたい". If you want to say you want to do two things in succession, you should use only one たい.

You can safely use たくて as the [te-form for reason/cause](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html), for example:

> ゲームをしたくて早起きした。
>     I wanted to play a game **so** I woke up early.

You may use two たい's when you list two independent desires, for example:

> お金持ちになりたくて有名にもなりたい。
>     I want to be rich, and I want to be famous, too.
>
> <sub>(お金持ちになりたいし有名にもなりたい (using [し](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28096/5010)) would be more common.)</sub>