# What does the し do in this sentence? "あそこのたべものはうまいしねだんもやすいです。"

Tags: grammar, particles

What does the し do in this sentence? "あそこのたべものはうまい**し**ねだんもやすいです。"

Comment: Related: [Usage of ”し” particle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28096/43676)

Comment: In this context, し is like "while" or "and". "The food there is delicious, and inexpensive (at the same time)".