# Is there any word 'popular' in 'お嬢ちゃんも先生似だしいけるんじゃねーか ?'?

Tags: translation, words, manga, anime

In some subtitles of S02E06 of the anime adaptation of the manga [The Quintessential Quintuplets](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93612/the-quintessential-quintuplets-aka-%e4%ba%94%e7%ad%89%e5%88%86%e3%81%ae%e8%8a%b1%e5%ab%81-is-%e5%b1%8a%e3%81%8f%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99-it-reaches-a-mondegreen), there's this line by a character named Shimoda, who was the student of now deceased character named Rena Nakano spoken to a character named Itsuki Nakano, who is the daughter of Rena Nakano.

The context of this scene is that Shimoda is explaining to Itsuki how beautiful Itsuki's mom was and how many students were a fan of Itsuki's mom for both beauty and personality.

> Given how much you resemble her, you're probably popular, too.

> [image]

that seems to be based on this line which I'm probably transcribing incorrectly from vol07ch57

> お嬢ちゃんも先生似だしいけるんじゃねーか ?

> [image]

that seems to translate

> Isn't the young lady like a teacher?

Or less literally

> Young lady, are/[aren't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question) you like Sensei?

**Question**: Is there technically no word '[popular](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95135/popular-%E3%83%A2%E3%83%86-vs-%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%97)' there (and then 'popular' is probably just used by the subtitle creators to refer to the scene immediately prior) ?

Comment: What does いける mean here?

Comment: @JimmyYang No idea. Maybe popular? See Angelos' answer.

Comment: Do you have any context before this scene? I'm not quite sure what this いける means here.

Comment: @broccolifacemask Edited to add: 'The context of this scene is that Shimoda is explaining to Itsuki how beautiful Itsuki's mom was and how many students were a fan of Itsuki's mom for both beauty and personality.'

Comment: @BCLC Oh in that case I guess it means "you probably have a chance (to be popular too)". Anyway it'll be nicer if you quote what is actually said rather than recapping, because the meaning of いける often depends on the previous sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> お嬢ちゃんも先生似**だしいけるんじゃねーか？**

For some reason your translation directly connects じゃねーか to 先生似 and ignores everything in between. し [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28096/usage-of-%E3%81%97-particle) is a particle indicating the preceding clause is a reason, and いける is where the translation takes 'popular'. I can't seem to find a dictionary entry for it, but it would probably an entry under definition 1 [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/). This いける generally means something like 'to be cool', 'to be good looking', or 'to work well' out of could meanings that apply to this scene. Also **ん**じゃないか is often less a tag question and more a statement of relative certainty.

Comment: Thanks Angelos. Idk that's what I got when I plugged it into the google translate. Lol. Actually when I add spaces to have 'お嬢ちゃんも先生似だし いけるん じゃねーか？' I get 'Isn't it possible for the young lady to look like a teacher?' So いける is what google translate thinks means 'to look like' ?

Comment: @BCLC 先生似 is the part that means 'looks like the teacher'

Comment: So the translation is like 'Young lady, since you look like Sensei, are/aren't you いける?' ? 'Young lady, are/aren't you いける like Sensei?' ? (I'm assuming in the context Sensei is really used as a title Sensei and not a common noun sensei btw.)

Comment: @BCLC Like I said, it might grammatically be a question, but んじゃないか is often more like 'I bet', 'I think', or as the translation up there put it, 'probably'.

Comment: 'Young lady, since you look like Sensei, I bet you're いけるtoo!' ?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, more or less

Comment: いけてる (in progressive) certainly means "cool" but I'm not sure いける can have the same meaning in this context...

Comment: @broccolifacemask Ohh, thank you, then I assume the meaning here is 'to work (well)'?

Comment: @Angelos Perhaps, but not exactly sure. Either way most of times when we use いける, there's expected to be a rough (Xは)Yがいける framework where Y is missing from the context.